# java script nested filter functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have an array called `restaurant_items`. It has `objects` which are the items of the restaurant and each object has an `array` called **in_menu** it also has `objects`.

I want to **filter** restaurant items which are belongs to an specific `menu_id`. Which means a nested filter function.

I want to pass menu_id 3 and get the items Burger and Pizza as expected output.

How do I achieve this using java script filters?

```js
const restaurant_items = [
{
 name:"Burger",
 in_menu:[{
 id:1,menu_id:3
 },{
 id:2,menu_id:5
 }
]
},
{
 name:"Pizza",
 in_menu:[{
 id:1,menu_id:3
 },{
 id:3,menu_id:9
 }
]
},
{
 name:"Donuts",
 in_menu:[{
 id:8,menu_id:6
 },{
 id:4,menu_id:8
 }
]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside the filter to get items with the specified menu id:

```js
const restaurant_items = [{"name":"Burger","in_menu":[{"id":1,"menu_id":3},{"id":2,"menu_id":5}]},{"name":"Pizza","in_menu":[{"id":1,"menu_id":3},{"id":3,"menu_id":9}]},{"name":"Donuts","in_menu":[{"id":8,"menu_id":6},{"id":4,"menu_id":8}]}]

const filterByMenuId = (menuId) =>
  restaurant_items.filter(item => item.in_menu.some(o => o.menu_id === menuId))
  
const result = filterByMenuId(3)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even I never heard that 'some' thing before. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter(restaurant_items, menu_id) {
    return restaurant_items.filter(function(item) {
        var index =  item.in_menu.findIndex(function(item2) {
            return item2.menu_id === menu_id;
        });
        return index !== -1;
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var filtered_items = filter(restaurant_items, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ori provided good solution. Adding one last map in end to just give you what you needed.

```
const getItem = (restaurant_items, inputId) => restaurant_items
    .filter(item => item.in_menu.some(menu_item => menu_item.id === inputId))
    .map(item => item.name);
```